# React: Getting Content from State Array Element

Tags: reactjs

I was experimenting with React State where one of the states is an array and I am trying to access one of the individual array elements. I found the line below problematic:

```
const Character = this.state.Characters[0];
```

If I use the above line in the code below, React would return error, however if I use:

```
const Character = somedefinedarray[0];
```

The below codes would work, but I could not see the difference for the two lines above at all. Can anyone enlighten me somehow? Might it be something related to "this" or state array access or so???

```
class Ch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Characters: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({Characters: somedefinedarray});
    }
    render() {
        const Character = this.state.Characters[0];
        return (
            <p>{Character.somestate}</p>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

During your first render, your default state is `Characters: []`.

So, when you access `Character = this.state.Characters[0];`, `Character` will be undefined because your state array is `empty`.

Then, you try to use `Character.somestate` which will result in an error saying, `cannot read property somestate of undefined`.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar accessing a non existent index of an array doesn't throw an error. It just returns `undefined`.